# Appcelerator Titanium - Substring Javascript: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, substring, appcelerator

I want to use Substring in Titanium (build 3.4) but i get this error:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [294,294] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,294] - In global/functions.js:48,25
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,295] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object 1388973670 has no  method 'substring'
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,296] - Source:     var lTime1 = mytime.substring(-1,1);
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at global/functions.js:48: Uncaught TypeError: Object 1388973670 has no method 'substring'
```

**This is my Code:**

```
var lTime1 = mytime.substring(-1,1);
```

i´ve also tried `slice` and `substr` ... came to the same result.

maybe you need to know that this is running on my android device... and its build for android

i dont know what to do and the only questions like mine that i can find are older than 4 years an use the same method... so i have no idea what i can do ^^
Thanks to every answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `mytime` is not a string, and does not have a method of `substring`. This is why it is throwing this exception.

You could cast `mytime` to a string, if it makes sense to.

```
var lTime1 = String(mytime).substring(-1,1);
```

Comment: oh my goodness ... you safed my day ! what a beginner fail... thank you so much!